# TCL string concat

Tags: string, tcl, concatenation

What is the recommended way of concatenation of strings?

Comment: Look also answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430093/how-to-concisely-concatenate-strings-in-tcl

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use **[append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/append.htm)**.

```
set result "The result is "
append result "Earth 2, Mars 0"
```

Answer (score 50):

Tcl does concatenation of strings as a fundamental operation; there's not really even syntax for it because you just write the strings next to each other (or the variable substitutions that produce them).

```
set combined $a$b
```

If you're doing concatenation of a variable's contents with a literal string, it can be helpful to put braces around the variable name or the whole thing in double quotes. Or both:

```
set combined "$a${b}c d"
```

Finally, if you're adding a string onto the end of a variable, use the [`append`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/append.htm) command; it's faster because it uses an intelligent memory management pattern behind the scenes.

```
append combined $e $f $g
# Which is the same as this:
set combined "$combined$e$f$g"
```

Comment: Note that the first argument to `append` is a variable name, just like the first arg to `set`.

Comment: This isn't really right in that you can't write arbitrary strings back-to-back and get their concatenation. E.g. `"a""b"` , or `{foo}"bar"` don't work. It's more true in awk, where something like `$1 ":" $2` _does_ work.

Answer (score 8):

If they are contained in variables, you can simply write `"$a$b"`.

Comment: I am doing exactly in the way you have written with a small difference like ${a}${b}, but I worry that it is not a correct way to do, is it?

Comment: They are both right - you would use the ${a}${b} construction in the case where you are building a string and there may be an ambiguity about the variable name e.g. set url /admin/item-edit?item_name=${item_id}name

Answer (score 2):

These days, you can concatenate two literal strings using the "string cat" command:

```
set newstring [string cat "string1" "string2"]
```